# MVC3/ASP.NET Best practice for ensuring a file argument is local and not trying to go outside of my application root directory?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, security, filenames

Another developer maintains a large collection of crystal reports. I need to make these reports available with my ASP.NET MVC3 page without requiring a full Crystal Reports Server product.

The current reporting site is a classic ASP page with all of the args passed e.g Prompt0&Prompt1...etc

To that end, I've created an aspx page that sits in my MVC app and serves these reports out of a directory in my app like so:

public partial class Report : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iLogger logger = LoggingFactory.CreateLogger();

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

        string fileName = Request.QueryString["reportfile"];


        if(!Regex.IsMatch(fileName,@"^[ 0-9a-zA-Z-_\\]+.rpt$"))
        {
      //log and throw
        }



        if(Path.IsPathRooted(fileName))
        {
           //log and throw
        }

        string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/");

        string path = Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName);



        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            rd.Load(path);
        }

        //get all keys starting with Prompt
        var prompts = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Where(q => q.StartsWith("Prompt"));

        foreach (string promptKey in prompts)
        {
            //try to convert the rest of the string to an int  
            //yes, this should probably not just be a replace here...
                string withoutPrompt = promptKey.Replace("Prompt", "");

                int promptVal;
                if (int.TryParse(withoutPrompt, out promptVal))
                {
                    rd.SetParameterValue(promptVal, Request.QueryString[promptKey]);
                }
                //rd.SetParameterValue(promptKey, Request.QueryString[promptKey]);

        }


        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;

    }
}
```

This works suprisingly well for the amount of effort (the report designer just needs to change the links within the report/query pages from e.g mywebserver.foo/Report1.rpt?Prompt....etc.etc to mywebserver.foo/mymvcreport/report.aspx?Filename=report1.rpt&Prompt... etc

So great, we can quickly move over to our MVC app and avoid having to have 10 sites go out and buy Crystal Server.

My obvious concern is that in the filename arg, someone could put just about anything in there, eg: "C:\foo\bar" or "../bla/blah",etc. Is there a single best practice for escaping these filenames and ensuring that it is a local path to my app?

I'd like to be able to take a parameter of eg: /Sales/Quarterly/Quarterly.rpt

My first thought is to just use a regex of eg [0-9a-zA-z-_\]+ to ensure no colon or dot characters can be used. Any suggestions on the most complete way to handle this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Updated with preliminary checks I put in...

Comment: Ok. So I started with checking ^[0-9a-zA-Z-_\\]+.rpt$ , and using Path.Combine to combine the two paths.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have assigned the right permissions to the application pool user this is something you shouldnt worry about.

Comment: Hm. That is not something I had even thought about! I am doing a security review using e.g Fortify and it was one of the higher scored findings, so I need to have some application-level protection against it as well though.